# Using MV to rename image files using a script

Tags: filenames, batch-rename, mv

I am trying to rename a set of Tiff images 001, 001 x, 002 , 002 x sequentially.
I am looking for the script to name image 001, 002, 003 and so on

This is the script I am running.

```
num=1
# Rename files 3 number
for file in *.tif; do
       mv -v "$file" "$(printf "%03d" $num).tif"
       let num=$num+1
done
```

When I run the script I get file 001, 004, 005
These file seem to become deleted.
001x'.tif -> 002.tif
002.tif -> 003.tif
when looking in the file I do not see file 002, 003.

What do I need to do to get my script to rename all files?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear that you're "*standing on the thing you're modifying*"...

For example, `*.tif` expands to `001.tif 001x.tif 002.tif 002x.tif`, and your loop then iterates through and renames them like this:

- `001.tif` → `001.tif`
- `001x.tif` → `002.tif` (replaces `002.tif`)
- `002.tif` → `003.tif` (originally `001x.tif`, now `003.tif`)
- `002x.tif` → `004.tif`
- etc...

The best and most simple solution to this problem would be to use two directories, for example take files from `./in/` and rename / move them into `./out/`:

```bsh
num=1

for file in ./in/*.tif; do
       mv -v "${file}" "./out/$(printf "%03d" ${num}).tif"
       num=$(( ${num} + 1 ))
done
```

This way you completely avoid the issue outlined above.

---

If you cannot or do not want to not use two directories, then the problem becomes much more complex immediately - you could need to resolve all sorts of naming conflicts between the input and ouput, and the order you perform the operations is critically important to avoid data loss. *I would not try to do this in a bash script...*

Comment: dose the above script create the dir out or do I need to make it first with a mkdir?

Comment: you'll need to make it yourself

Answer (score 0):

I got this work

cd $path
num=1
for file in *.tif; do
mv -v "${file}" "$path/$(printf "%03d" ${num}).tif"
num=$(( ${num} + 1 ))
done

How do I add
suffix="x"
to the end of the filename?